# Map Quickbooks QBXML nodes to Ipp.Data objects

Tags: c#, quickbooks, quickbooks-online, qbxml

Is there such a thing to convert QBXML XmlNodes to IPP.Data objects in C#.

For instance, CustomerRet returned in a CustomerQueryRs could be mapped to a Intuit.Ipp.Data.Customer

Answer (score 0):

There is not a conversion. At this point there shouldn't be a need to convert from QBXML to the IPP data, since access to desktop data in the cloud is being deprecated.

Comment: I am using a WebConnector. This is not deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no tool for this.

Personally, I keep QBD and QBO integration code in separate silos because of their differences and to aid in troubleshooting.